# Why did my tablet stop switching to widescreen when connected to my TV through HDMI?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hdmi

I have a tablet PC running Android **v4.0.3.** Up until recently, when I connected it to my TV it automatically switched to widescreen (**16:10**) format.

Something has changed, and now it always displays as the old narrow screen format. There doesn't appear to be a setting for this on the tablet.

It's a NATPC M0009 in case that makes a difference.

Has anyone had a similar issue, or can anyone point me towards a solution?

Comment: You might want to specify the make and model of your tablet in case it's a device/manufacturer-specific problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've locked the format on the TV instead of setting Auto-switching. Check the TV settings.